# Download file with different local name using wget

Tags: shell, sed, awk, wget

Hi i have a text file where download links are given like -

```
http://www.example.com/10.10.11/abc.jpg
http://www.example.com/10.10.12/abc.jpg
http://www.example.com/10.10.13/abc.jpg
```

Here 10.10.* is the date of the image.

I need to download all the images using wget where the image name will be the corresponding date (eg. 10.10.111.jpg).

**PS.** I tried using:

```
wget -i download.txt
```

So, any solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can [instruct Wget to create subdirectories](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Directory-Options) based on the URL, and then do the renaming after the download has finished.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a batch script that downloads the files one by one using the `-O` option, and a bit of sed/awk magic to get the names right

But careful! given the `-O` option, you *have* to call wget on a per file basis

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
#!/bin/sh
while read url; do
   urldir=${url%/*}
   dir=${urldir##*/}
   wget -O $dir.jpg $url
done < download.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '\|/\([^/]*\)/[^/]*\1[^/.]*.jpg|!d' download.txt | wget -i -
```

Explanation:

Filter the `download.txt` file to contain only those files which you require and then pass them on to `wget`.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a script that does just this [bulkGetter](http://esausilva.com/2012/10/20/bulkgetter-a-script-wrapped-around-wget/). Super easy to use, you just need an input file with all the links you want to download and use option "-rb" (refer to link).